# MySQL++ - Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable was corrupted

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, xdebug, mysql++

im having issues with MySQL++ and desperately need help.
I'm using Visual Studio 2010, MySQL++ v3.1.0 and MySQL v5.1.59( x86 & x64 );
All Library's have been compiled correctly. This error only occurs in Debug version due to the compiler setting "Both (/RTC1, equiv. to /RTCsu) (/RTC1)" being on.

Edit: I should note that this only happens in Debug version. In Release it works like a charm
I've tracked the problem back to the mysqlpp_d.dll, the MySQL++ object are crashing on there destructors due to reference counting. It complains about not being capable of accessing the memory of the ref counter, and when it tries to decrease it, it crashes. At least thats what I think happens.

I tried this to make sure everything gets derefrenced and removed in the correct order (even tho its irrelevant, but helped me track the true problem down I hope): http://pastebin.com/Ru0uYcy9

It crashes with:

First-chance exception at 0x000007feeef5dd4c (mysqlpp_d.dll) in Launcher.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x000007feeeff5148.
Unhandled exception at 0x000007feeef5dd4c (mysqlpp_d.dll) in Launcher.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x000007feeeff5148.

And breakes here:
http://pastebin.com/9Mfr7NwB

Comment: Are you linking the Debug version of the library with the Debug version of your application ?

Comment: Yes, i've made sure everthing was linked correctly in all versions.

Comment: Ok, I've done some more debugging and created a fresh console project. And I received no error.
The only difference in between the two is that one is a DLL project and the other a Console project, but I doubt this is the problem considering the code works, just the memory handling doesn't.
This brings me to the conclusion that the Engine im working with, does some kind of memory management the affects how MySQL++ handles its memory.

Comment: The only option I see now is to somehow disable the engines memory manager before the MySQL++ code is run, and re enable it afterwards.
Ive tried undefining and redefining different memory specific defines, which had no effect and still left me with the error.

Is it possible to flip on default memory management and turn it back off during run time?
Or is it maybe possible to temporarily disable this specific warning/error during run time and then reactivate it?

Comment: From the error, it could still be a runtime mismatch (Debug/Release, which you say it isn't, or MD/MT) between the library and the application: when you allocate library objects on the stack, the application reserve the space for the object, but its the library function/constructor that fills it, and if the library is compiled with options that differ from the application options, and these options make the size of some members different between the application and the library, the reserved space might be insufficient and some data might be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

This code has a serious bug:

```
mysqlpp::UseQueryResult res;
{
    mysqlpp::Query query = conn.query();
    query << "SELECT USER();";
    res = query.use();
    row = res.fetch_row();
}
```

You aren't consuming all the result sets. In MySQL, stored procedures that return data return at least two separate result sets: the first is the results you asked for, and the second is status information about the call itself. See `examples/multiquery.cpp` in the MySQL++ source distribution for the correct way to handle this. Also see [section 3.16](http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/doc/html/userman/tutorial.html#concurrentqueries) in the MySQL++ user manual.

The main consequence of this is that later queries on the same connection will fail.

I think your memory corruption is actually a secondary effect, and that the primary problem stems from ignoring the MySQL C API's attempts to tell you that you're trying to run two overlapping queries on the same connection, because you didn't consume the entire first result set. From what little code you've posted, I can see that you're ignoring returned error codes, so if you've also disabled MySQL++ exceptions, your code will completely ignore this error and blithely go on to stomp all over things it shouldn't.

By the way, please lose the trailing semicolon on the query. It isn't needed with the C API, and can cause confusion, especially in the face of multi-queries. Use semicolons only to separate multiple statements in a single query.